How do you get StrawberryShake to treat ID as a number?
I am using the startgg GraphQL schema which has an id field for some objects, and StrawberryShake tries to parse it as a String. The schema has this
type Event {
  id: ID
  ...
}

The specification has this
scalar ID

And at runtime, I get this error
System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation requires an element of type 'String', but the target element has type 'Number'.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonElementWrongTypeException(JsonTokenType expectedType, JsonTokenType actualType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.CheckExpectedType(JsonTokenType expected, JsonTokenType actual)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.GetString(Int32 index, JsonTokenType expectedType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.GetString()
   at StartGG.GraphQL.State.GraphQLClientEntityIdFactory.ParseEventEntityId(JsonElement obj, String type)
   at StartGG.GraphQL.State.GraphQLClientEntityIdFactory.Parse(JsonElement obj)
   at StartGG.GraphQL.State.GetNumberOfEntrantsBuilder.Update_IGetNumberOfEntrants_EventEntity(IEntityStoreUpdateSession session, Nullable`1 obj, ISet`1 entityIds)
   at StartGG.GraphQL.State.GetNumberOfEntrantsBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<BuildData>b__0(IEntityStoreUpdateSession session)
   at StrawberryShake.EntityStore.Update(Action`1 action)
   at StartGG.GraphQL.State.GetNumberOfEntrantsBuilder.BuildData(JsonElement obj)
   at StrawberryShake.OperationResultBuilder`1.Build(Response`1 response)

Kind of disappointing that the biggest graphql project for Maui does not even handle the graphql provided by startgg correctly.
Is there not a way to tell it to parse the ID as a long?
The generated code has this nugget which seems incredibly short-sighted of the developers:
Deserialize_String(global::StrawberryShake.Json.JsonElementExtensions.GetPropertyOrNull(obj, "id"))

How do I fix this in .Net Maui?


Kind of disappointing that the biggest graphql project for Maui does
not even handle the graphql provided by startgg correctly.

Lets check this out:
https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types
More specifically this part:

ID: A unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key
for a cache. The ID type is serialized in the same way as a String;
however, defining it as an ID signifies that it is not intended to be
human‐readable.

The point behind this is that there are all kinds of IDs.
You want integer long. Someone else wants GUID as string. Someone else wants base64 encoded jpg image of a fruit. (I wish I was joking about the last part, but I did receive this as API specification, and had to work with it.)
So, first - get your String.
And then do whatever you want to do with it.

I could not get the string because strawberry shake's JSON parser parses it as a number and I get the exception in the post, and my research seems to suggest that strawberry shake hard codes that behavior into the parser. I ended up using GraphQL.Client and their parser is much more flexible and user friendly and, more importantly, works out of the box.

@JohnGlen Do you get this exception when trying to parse to String?

No, I give strawberry shake a graphql query and it throws when I call ExecuteAsync(). It is a bug in their code that, based on my reading, they do not want to fix.
